# Как не ошибиться в таких словах?

Tags: грамматика, склонение, причастия

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как склоняются слова на *-шийся, -щийся, -шегося, -шихся, -шимися* и т. д. Объясните эту грамматику на примерах, чтобы можно было понять.
Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Слова, оканчивающиеся на *-шийся*, *-щийся*, — это [возвратные причастия](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/vozvratnoe-i-nevozvratnoe-prichastie).

Как и прилагательные, такие причастия согласуются с определяемыми существительными в роде, числе и падеже, а их окончание можно определить по вопросу, который к ним задаётся (кроме формы мужского рода именительного падежа), + постфикс *-ся*.

Если в окончании вопроса буква присутствует буква **о** (*как**о**го?*), то в окончании причастия пишется **е** (+ся) — *воздержавш**е**гося*, если в окончании вопроса имеется **и** (*как**и**ми?*), то и в окончании причастия пишется **и** (+ся) — *воздержавш**и**мися*.

Пример:
И. п. — оперившийся (м. р.), оперившаяся (ж. р.), оперившееся (ср. р.), оперившиеся (мн. ч.);
Р. п. — оперившегося, оперившейся, оперившегося, оперившихся;
Д. п. — оперившемуся, оперившейся, оперившемуся, оперившимися;
В. п. — оперившегося (одуш.), оперившийся (неодуш.), оперившуюся, оперившееся, оперившихся (одуш.), оперившиеся (неодуш.);
Т. п. — оперившимся, оперившейся, оперившеюся, оперившимся, оперившимися;
П. п. — оперившемся, оперившейся, оперившемся, оперившихся.

*Все та же тишина была ответом на одинокий рев его еще не **оперившегося голоса*** (Илья Бояшов. Танкист, или «Белый тигр»).
*Перелесок кончился, выбежав на круто поднявшийся берег двумя тонкими, едва **оперившимися деревцами*** (Сергей Бабаян. Господа офицеры).

[Склонение причастий](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/morfologiya/sklonenie_prichastiy.html)
[Светящийся](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F) (склонение)